# Find element in json file

Tags: c#, json

I have `JSON` file like below, and I want to find a specific string or list of strings in this file.
I need to know if the values are in this file:

```
{
    "naglowek": {
        "dataGenerowaniaDanych": "20200107",
        "liczbaTransformacji": "5000",
        "schemat": "RRRRMMDDNNNNNNNNNNBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB, gdzie R to cyfra roku, M – miesiąca, D - dnia daty generowania pliku, N to cyfra NIPu, a B to cyfra rachunku bankowego"
    },
    "skrotyPodatnikowCzynnych": [
        "0000023d01e60fa522c2535d37c93051bdb9bc74e31b824460cd743a66a5282abb45567e43f09cfb26cd454b75ee6d6b0dfa83ef26db33581510afa421c3d430",
        "0000025fe2175d2639990a7918baf727c41bbf554b1a88b679e32f3dc460c4dc44454b6a98417c31c4f2ee9e1c705ff951a1d7601553b327ec380213f2186a0f",
        "00000cd37d8ded5c477552f61b647bcf9e6a967036823b7515b1e01e7fe3fe1854c470fb30f56beef1bc80d83d7350a53fe8677cb932f4f251837a767e0f8d63",
        "00000d939549219dd4cd795c9b9680a3e5147791b1ddc4148f3463d6b3aa22849bcc30729cc60fc1282977d52d635c70d353f450c2abaef22f7d22439ac7b6e6",
        "00001df757bb678d654308b1137c7dc8381d0457043009f4fc63edab93b32f60e1f460375e7da6965dbfd58f447d173c4c6c42add0d3dac181816782cf297cd8",
        "0000248aef22c8ebddebd272cdc03e023f1dca221a5c7a731ade2989f1996b00b440c7410d52b89ef6f7927608bed66ad42a230f8e2cf86b97037597640d1da0",
        "00002c000cd48dc44e63fa56d314962ff16b08c2e135a4c5352261a8e1c6b6fed9fefa01f01494d554e3158039450811a727c32576656d80963ed7b81a3732e3",
        "00003666894d6872169f1f5212ba30a7441580f90d115823ca2d9cb6c5aca6e58ce277943bb284dd52cd669e8f05adba8d406ea8fb81c3e26bfce46b1cf8f120",
        "00003bb55a8f67914ff5553a42f2bf2c8456b4f5d1a140ffdb1069442122114c61ad7bcbc715b35862c9e4566a8ddfbe9d9ca25457daa4cda51cdd796252b770",
        "000041debf38337bb23391ccc9624483370a4e2d63dc4634c4f7c8d9071e5337d65464e59feedebe082bb7cbf6bb0a132b92194be457c92b1111132a51c81dcf",
        "00004c88c01bc05ed4aa0df33cdbbe41aa77d49f94a6c9ee35efe6a59eca5cdea735acff28f05fb3d960973227b27ec81444b9afe14323fd2fc53a991b42c6ce"]
}
```

I need to find in this file specific string (one of the hashes)
I tried this:

```
public bool FindInFile(string sha512, string filePath, string date)
    {
      JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(filePath + date + ".json"));
      // read JSON directly from a file
      using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(filePath + date + ".json"))
      using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
      {
        JObject o2 = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        IEnumerable<JToken> pricyProducts = o2.SelectTokens("[?($.skrotyPodatnikowCzynnych == " + sha512 + ")]");
      }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: what **is** the problem?

Comment: you can iterate over the `o1` object `JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(filePath + date + ".json"));`. It is a parsed json nodes  list (`IDictionary<string, JToken?>` actually)

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure the file is a valid json and do not contain other fields, why bother parsing it ? just look for the strings in it...

Otherwise just use linq to see if the query you wrote yields Any result...

```
pricyProducts.Any()
```

If it does not return any results ever, just fix the query (which i think is wrong)...
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm

```
o2.SelectTokens("[?($.skrotyPodatnikowCzynnych == " + sha512 + ")]")
```

probably should be

```
o2.SelectTokens("$.skrotyPodatnikowCzynnych[?(@ == '" + sha512 + "')]"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
public bool FindInFile(string sha512, string filePath, string date)
{    
    var obj = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(filePath + date + ".json"));
    return obj["skrotyPodatnikowCzynnych"].Children().Values<string>().Contains(sha512);
}
```